# Core Service and RTF Field update in Component

Tags: core-service

I want to update the contents of an RTF field with the Core Service.  In the process, I convert it to an XDocument and back - maybe it's not needed and causes the issue, not sure.  I'm using XDocument to quickly find the field I need in the XML.

The result is that the RTF Design tab shows the HTML and in the source it is HTMLEncoded.  I have no idea why.

[image]

Code:

```
private void UpdateComp()
{
    // Load
    string namespaceUri = TridionXmlHelper.GetNamespaceUri(component, client);
    NameTable nt = new NameTable();
    XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("tridion", namespaceUri);
    XmlDocument compXml = new XmlDocument(nt);
    compXml.LoadXml(content);

    string fieldName = "body";

    // Update RTF field
    var xDoc = compXml.ToXDocument();
    var compField = from p in xDoc.Descendants()
                   where p.Name.LocalName == fieldName
                   select p;

    var body = compField.First();
    var fieldXml = "<body xmlns=\"uuid:f06437fa-826d-4ef1-8214-ceed0847bf84\">This is a <strong xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">bold</strong> test</body>";

    // replace some simple text and save
    body.Value = fieldXml.Replace("test", "<em>test</em>");

    // Save
    compXml = xDoc.ToXmlDocument();
    component.Content = compXml.InnerXml;
    client.CheckOut(component.Id, true, new ReadOptions());
    client.Save(component, new ReadOptions());
    client.CheckIn(component.Id, true, "", new ReadOptions());
}


// from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508572/converting-xdocument-to-xmldocument-and-vice-versa
public static class DocumentExtensions
{
    public static XmlDocument ToXmlDocument(this XDocument xDocument)
    {
        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        using (var xmlReader = xDocument.CreateReader())
        {
            xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
        }
        return xmlDocument;
    }

    public static XDocument ToXDocument(this XmlDocument xmlDocument)
    {
        using (var nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDocument))
        {
            nodeReader.MoveToContent();
            return XDocument.Load(nodeReader);
        }
    }
}


public static string GetNamespaceUri(ComponentData comp, CoreServiceClient client)
{
    LinkToSchemaData schemaLink = comp.Schema as LinkToSchemaData;
    SchemaData schema = client.Read(schemaLink.IdRef, new ReadOptions()) as SchemaData;
    string namespaceUri = schema.NamespaceUri;

    return namespaceUri;
}
```

Comment: Turns out I cannot use an XDocument for this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271080/c-sharp-xml-avoid-html-encode-using-xdocument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use XmlDocument and not XDocument.   Solution code below.

```
private void UpdateComp()
{
    string compUri = "tcm:10-61203";
    var component = (ComponentData)client.Read(compUri, new ReadOptions());
    string content = component.Content;

    // Load
    string namespaceUri = TridionXmlHelper.GetNamespaceUri(component, client);
    NameTable nt = new NameTable();
    XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("tridion", namespaceUri);
    XmlDocument compXml = new XmlDocument(nt);
    compXml.LoadXml(content);
    string fieldName = "body";
    var field = compXml.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='" + fieldName + "']");
    field.Item(0).InnerXml = field.Item(0).InnerXml.Replace("test", "<em xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">test</em>");

    // Save
    component.Content = compXml.OuterXml;
    client.CheckOut(component.Id, true, new ReadOptions());
    client.Save(component, new ReadOptions());
    client.CheckIn(component.Id, true, "", new ReadOptions());
}


// from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508572/converting-xdocument-to-xmldocument-and-vice-versa
public static class DocumentExtensions
{
    public static XmlDocument ToXmlDocument(this XDocument xDocument)
    {
        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        using (var xmlReader = xDocument.CreateReader())
        {
            xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
        }
        return xmlDocument;
    }

    public static XDocument ToXDocument(this XmlDocument xmlDocument)
    {
        using (var nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDocument))
        {
            nodeReader.MoveToContent();
            return XDocument.Load(nodeReader);
        }
    }
}


public static string GetNamespaceUri(ComponentData comp, CoreServiceClient client)
{
    LinkToSchemaData schemaLink = comp.Schema as LinkToSchemaData;
    SchemaData schema = client.Read(schemaLink.IdRef, new ReadOptions()) as SchemaData;
    string namespaceUri = schema.NamespaceUri;

    return namespaceUri;
}
```